# Plotting each day data side by side in one graph matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have 15 days data in 15 separate text files. Each file contains two columns [x,y], [x] in hours and [y] is distance travelled. [x] column are same but [y] columns are different from one file to another. Here, I have sample data for 2 days

```
Day1

x    y

1    10
2    8
3    8.5
4    6
5    9

Day2

x    y

1    11
2    9
3    9.5
4    6.8
5    9.4
```

I am trying to plot in a sigle graph the variation of [y] per day so that the each day appears along x-axis. To be more clear, I can plot for Day1, plot(x,y). Then for Day2, I still want plot(x,y), but [x] repeated along x-axis. Something like this:

[image]

As can be seen in this example plot, the plot for Day1 is ending at 24 then the plot for Day2 again start from 24 or 0. In this way, I want a visualization for 15 days.

Comment: Okay, and I am guessing you have some problems with that? Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Edited question for clarity.

Comment: Still, what do you want to do? Boxplots, mean+sd per day? Be as specific as can be, show the code you used and show where you are stuck.

Comment: Edited once again.

Comment: Won't it be nicer to visualize it by stacking all days 1d data in a matrix and then plot the image by say imagsc?

Comment: I would recommend using a time series for this. 
(https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeseries.html)
I'm assuming your 5 measurements per day means you have 1 measurement every 6 hours, however i find it strange that in your example, the first measurement on day 2 is not equal to the last one of day 1. Anyway, you can create a timeseries for each day and as long as you set the starting dates to subsequent days you should be able to plot them all together in one figure and the x-axis will automatically be date-time.

Comment: There might be more useful ways to visualize you data, as suggested e.g. by matanj, but regardless - the most straightforward solution would be to add `24` to each consecutive dataset, then modify the x-labels of your plot (to go from and add a few annotations for the different days. Did you try _that_?